# How can I close my worksheet function in vba?

Tags: vba

How can I close my worksheets if it doesn't match or if I click on cancel. If I click on cancel it keeps on taking me back to enter the worksheets. Here is my code.

```
   Function WorksheetExists(WSName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = Worksheets(WSName).Name = WSName


    On Error GoTo 0
   End Function

    Do Until WorksheetExists(shname)
     shname = InputBox("Enter sheet name")
       If Not WorksheetExists(shname) Then
         MsgBox shname & " doesn't exist!", vbExclamation

       Else
        WSName = shname

         Sheets(shname).Select
       End If
       Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for a blank response.  It keeps looping since you don't have an empty string as a sheet name.

```
    Do Until WorksheetExists(shname)
        shname = InputBox("Enter sheet name")
        If shname = "" Then
            Exit Do
        ElseIf Not WorksheetExists(shname) Then
            MsgBox shname & " doesn't exist!", vbExclamation
        Else
            WSName = shname
            Sheets(shname).Select
        End If
    Loop
```

or

```
Do Until WorksheetExists(shname) Or shname = ""
    shname = InputBox("Enter sheet name")
    If Not WorksheetExists(shname) Then
        MsgBox shname & " doesn't exist!", vbExclamation
    Else
        WSName = shname
        Sheets(shname).Select
    End If
Loop
```